# why would you assign this to another variable?

Tags: javascript

At the start of [the source code for underscore.js](http://documentcloud.github.com/underscore/docs/underscore.html), you see this:

```
var root = this;

var previousUnderscore = root._;
```

So the question becomes why didnt the author just write:

```
var previousUnderscore = this._;
```

Comment: Because he is using the root and previousUnderscore separately in code

Comment: Because the execution context (= the value of the `this` keyword) is not available in nested functions (since they have their own execution context). Therefore, if you want to access it from within those nested functions, you'll have to "save" it in a variable.

Comment: I like Sime Vidas' answer the best, but I cannot accept it because it was provided as a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two reasons,

1. Readability, it makes it clearer what the code is doing, what it is referencing.  this is very opaque.
2. depending on context, this can refer to lots and lots and lots of differnt objects, root may be used in multiple place and will always refer to the correct object.